# How to add custom logic on redirectTo field in Angular?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use `redirectTo` with custom logic?

I have this routes (`forRoot`):

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: ':companyId',
    canActivate: [CanActivateCompany],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: () => { /* check here in localstorage if key is exist when go to /{key} otherwise go to /unkown-company */} },
];
```

My use case is when the url is navigate to `/` or empty then I want to decide which url to redirect to. (check here in localstorage if key is exist when go to /{key} otherwise go to /unkown-company).

The urls can be:

```
www.example.com/apple
www.example.com/apple/login
www.example.com/unkown-company
www.example.com/unkown-company/login
```

And in `CanActivateCompany` I check if the `companyId` param and redirect to `/` or `login` child route.

Comment: Why not redirecting directly inside CanActivateCompany ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use `redirectTo` as a function or any other type. It's a string type according to [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#redirectTo:%7E:text=A%20URL%20to%20redirect%20to%20when%20the%20path%20matches.).

You need to do your logic check in your `CanActivateCompany`.

```js
class CanActivateCompany implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _router: ) {}

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    
    const id = route.snapshot.params.id;
    const companyId = localStorage.getItem(id);
   
    if(companyId !== null)
      return true;

    this._router.navigate(['SOME_REDIRECT_PATH']);
  }
}
```